# NSTextView: loading RTF, view does not update correctly until mouse is moved over the control

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextview

I have a pretty simple window that contains an NSTextView. I'm calling [readRTFDFromFile:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to load and display an rtf file on disk. I'm calling this from within the awakeFromNib handler. When the view appears on screen it only partially displays the contents of the rtf, the button portion of the view is blank/white.

However, when the mouse is moved over the control, the rest of the rtf is correctly rendered, filling the previously blank space.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to post your code. Also, there is no "the" awakeFromNib handler. Any object can have it, so it's best to explain where that is too.

Comment: good point. i'm calling this from within the NSWindowController's awakeFromNib handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A photo of the view would help immensely, but have you tried marking the view as needing display (`[view setNeedsDisplay:YES]`) after reading in the RTF data?

Answer (score 5):

turn off "non-contiguous layout" in interface builder

Comment: THIS! Wow, I spent several weeks blocked on this on and off, very hard to find answer.